# Clarification on meaning of "Gaussian random variable"

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, definition, intuition

When my lecturer uses the word Gaussian random variable, he always writes the pdf of the Gaussian instead of the random variable itself.

For example,

> given a random variable $X$ Gaussian, $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{-2} x^2)$

I am so confused as to why can't we talk about $X$ itself without using pdf?

Recall the definition of random variable is a function $X$ that maps outcomes to the real numbers i.e. $X: \zeta \to \mathbb{R}$

In this case, given $X$ is Gaussian, what are the outcomes of the sample space and what is the value that $X$ has assigned to outcomes of the sample space?

Comment: The thing being exponentiated is probably $-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$. The special case $\mu=0$ gives $-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}$.

Comment: The density is $$f_X(x) = \frac 1 {\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left( \frac{-x^2} {2\sigma^2} \right).$$ In other words, the $\sigma^2$ on the inside should be in the denominator. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain of $X$ is $\Omega$, which can literally be anything. For example $X(\text{ I roll a six}) = 1$

So when I roll a six, the random value $X$ takes on the value $1$. So random variables "transfer" events into real numbers (in reality, things are more general; you need not to have $\mathbb R$  )

Now the point is that you have no idea "how often " does $X$ takes on the value $1$, because it depends on what happens in the real world ie. If I roll a six or not.

So $X$ is actually deterministic, it associates to certain events certain values. The idea then is that if you know the probabilities of certain events happening, you know the probability that $X$ takes on a certain value.

So technically we defin $\Omega$, a probability $P$ on $\Omega$, which induces through the relation $X$ a probability $P_X$ on the reals. 
In practice we just assign $P_X$ (for example a gaussian ) and we don't specify $\Omega$ and $P$

Comment: thanks, but can you clarify one more thing for me. Suppose I am a highschool teacher, I have students aged from 1 - 100, and I measure their height to generate a set $Y$ = {....} all the heights. Then I go to excel and plot the heights. Is the plot generated can be thought of as the image of a random variable? In other words, are all statistical plots the image of random variables? And when we say that a data has a certain distribution, for example uniform distribution, is that equivalent as saying that the data was generated by uniform random variable?

Comment: No, it cannot be anything at all.  It cannot be the set of six numbers you can get by rolling a die.  There is no function whose domain is that set that is normally distributed. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant 1) Yes. The random variable is $X(\text{this particular person's genes for height}) = \text{his height in cm}$. By the way you see why we don't usually care too much about the sample space, we don't even know what that is! 2) Random variables don't generate data, they associate events to numbers. Saying that means that the probability of the events happening is such that, through the random variable $X$, each real number on (say) [0,1] is equally likely to come up. You can just think of it as "every number is equally likely to come up"

Comment: @MichaelHardy I was not talking about the normal distribution,  it was just an example to show that the domain of $X$ is a sigma algebra usually made up of events such as rolling a dice, rather than an usual function from the reals. I was specifically addressing a comment the OP left in another answer asking the difference between $f_X(x)$ and $X(x)$

Comment: @Ant : The domain of $X$ is not a sigma-algebra.  The domain of a probability measure is a sigma-algebra of subsets of the domain of $X$. Typically one has a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ in which $\mathcal F$ is a sigma-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ and $P$ is a probabliity measure whose domain is the sigma-algebra $\mathcal F$.  But domain of a random variable $X$ would be $\Omega$, not $\mathcal F$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Oh, of course. I got completely confused there! Corrected, thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is infinitely many random variables with the same pdf (Gaussian in this case). In probability theory is very common to study all the random variables with the same pdf, so there is no need to talk about a specific random variable. What really matters is to understand the general properties of these random variables, and one way to study these properties is studying their pdf.

Answer (score 1):

For each expected value and each variance there is only one normal distribution, so if one says that $X$ is normally distributed with expected value $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ then one has said what its distribution is. Often one writes something like this:

> > Suppose $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.  Then [conclusions follow].

That does not involve mentioning a density, and that is what is usually done.

The outcomes in the sample space can be any of a number of different things.  Sometimes one considers an infinite sequence $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ of independent random variables, and an outcome is an infinite sequence of numbers. In such a case normally the value of $X_1$ at an outcome that is a particular sequence would be the first number in the sequence and $X_2$ would be the second one, and so on.

Comment: Are most/all statistical time series generated by random variables? Given any data, are we able to map it back to some random variable? (I have only studied probability but not statistics so data has no probabilistic significance to me.)

Comment: Probably most are _modeled_ by assuming they are realizations of a sequence of random variables. ${}\qquad{}$